# Passing a Private variable to a view inside a controller function

Tags: codeigniter

I have a controller defined as such fashion

```
class product  extends CI_Controller{
    private $pagesize = 1;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        @session_start();
    }

function view_product()
{
   $result['pagesize'] = $this->pagesize;
   $this->load->view("view_product',$result);

}
```

Now,

in this line `$result['pagesize'] = $this->pagesize;` i am trying to pass the private variable pagesize into the $result['pagesize'], but somehow the variable isnt passing.

i dont know what mistake i am doing, its seems to be a silly one..

Comment: small catch here "view_product' close quotes properly, what you get if you `echo $pagesize` in view_product.

Comment: undefined variable error

Comment: is there a typo here `"view_product'`. Double quotes-single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried and it worked.

**Controller:**

```
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller
{
    private $var = "hello";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function function_name()
    {
         $data["my_variable"] = $this->var;
         $this->load->view("my_view", $data);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php

    echo $my_variable;          // hello
```

Comment: your answer is absolutely right, i event did that myself, but dont why why, its not working. Anyways thanks